# Showing the output of a named pipe from VirtualBox

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, named-pipe

I created a named pipe in VirtualBox, and I found some pages explaining how to read it's output using Putty, but I don't want to use that. Since Putty is just a frontend to ssh (right?), I would rather like to use something like that. I'm running Windows and also have Cygwin installed, so how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

All this is doing is using PUTTY as a serial console rather than its more usual use for SSH.

You can use any tool that is capable of listening to a virtual serial port. PowerShell, Node.JS or Python for example each have libraries to do this. Or any of the "old fashioned" terminal tools we used to use when connecting over modems to Bulletin Boards. :)  Hyperterminal is available on some versions of Windows.

All you are doing is giving the software the address of the pipe instead of the more normal COMx: address.

Not sure but I would think you could reference the pipe from Cygwin but that just seems a little over-complex. Minicom or screen would be the normal tools to use on a Linux box.

Answer (score 0):

I believe PuTTY has its own SSH implementation, rather than just being a frontend to OpenSSH.  But it also supports Telnet, serial ports, and other things.

So it can perhaps be better thought of as a multi-purpose terminal, rather than an SSH frontend.

You could try Plink, which is essentially a command-line version of PuTTY that runs in the console.

I have had success with a command like this for a Hyper-V named pipe:

```
plink -serial \\.\pipe\MyPipe -sercfg 115200,8,1,N,N
```

If you get something like `Error 5: Access is denied`, try in an administrative command prompt.